# XNA Spritebatch.End() with Class doesn't work when started

Tags: c#, xna

XNA spritebatch.End(); with a class doesn't work and it is saying: 'XNA Framework Reach profile requires TextureAddressMode to be Clamp when using texture sizes that are not powers of two.' when started. And it doesn't show any error's either. How can I solve this? Please help!!

```
 public override void Draw()
    {
        Statics.SPRITEBATCH.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearWrap, null,null);

        Statics.SPRITEBATCH.Draw(this.background, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);

        foreach (var item in Tuyaux)
        {
            item.Draw();
        }

        Statics.SPRITEBATCH.Draw(this.sand, new Vector2(0, 529), Color.White);

        Scroll.Draw();

        Bird.Draw();

        Statics.SPRITEBATCH.DrawString(this.Font, "Score : " + this.score.ToString(), new Vector2(10, 10), Color.Red);

        if (Bird.dead)
        {
            // rode gloed over het spel als het gameover is.
            Statics.SPRITEBATCH.Draw(Statics.PIXEL, new Rectangle(0,0, Statics.GAME_WIDTH,Statics.GAME_HEIGHT), new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.3f));
            // gameover achtergrond laten zien.
            Statics.SPRITEBATCH.Draw(this.gameover, new Vector2(0, 80), Color.White);
        }

        Statics.SPRITEBATCH.End(); 
        base.Draw();
    }
```

Comment: what does "with a class" mean? I am pretty sure that indeed, you just have to use texture sizes that are powers of two since you compile against the Reach profile and don't use Clamp! What dimensions are `this.background`, `this.sand`, `Statics.PIXEL` (1x1 i hope) and `this.gameover`? I suspect that you are drawing to the same `SpriteBatch` in your own `Draw` methods... check used textures there as well. The exception tells exactly what is going wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly what the exception tells you:

You are targetting the Reach profile, so either all your texture dimensions must be powers of two or you have to use clamp as adress mode. So:

- **If you don't need wrapping**, try replacing `SamplerState.LinearWrap` with `SamplerState.LinearClamp` in your `Statics.SPRITEBATCH.Begin` call.
- If you **need** wrapping textures, make sure all of them have dimensions that are powers of two
- Last but not least, if it is an option for you, you may simply use the `HiDef` profile instead of `Reach`